# Compiling and Dev Mode

Tags: gwt

I recently upgraded from classic dev mode and older version of eclipse. This new Super Dev Mode is super confusing. In the console it says to visit  `"http://127.0.0.1:9876/recompile/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApp?_callback=cback&user.agent=safari,gecko1_8,ie8,ie9,ie10"`

I do so and it compiles the 6 permutations. However when I put it on my server in the bottom right there is this little circular arrow that says "gwt" beside it. When I click on it it changes to "compiling..... etc".

I just want to compile the app and host it on the server. Why is that gwt circular arrow on my host page?

Comment: Which version of GWT and Eclipse are you using? Try using the URL of your HTML page the module is included. To host the final compiled version you have to rightclick on the project and choose GWT -> Compile.

Comment: @mxlse Right clicking and compiling got me what I needed. Thanks! If you add that as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To host the final compiled version you have to rightclick on the project and choose **GWT -> Compile** in Eclipse. When you compile the project like that the GWT Compiler will also leave out things like `GWT.log()` depending on your configuration to optimize the resulting JS files.